# how to find out the 50% 75% and 90% point in cumulative distribution function in R

Tags: r, cdf

I have a huge amount of data and I used `ecdf` function in R to calculate the cumulative distribution function. However, I can't figure out how can I get the 50% or 75% point in this function.

For example,

0.5 = Fn(x)

How can I find the x value or is there any way to print out the function directly in R rather than draw the graph.

Comment: Look at the `?quantile` function. You can either pass the function obtained from `ecdf` or directly the data from which the function was generated. For instance `quantile(x,c(.5,.75))` where `x` is the vector containing your data, or `y<-ecdf(x);quantile(y,c(.5,.75))`.

Comment: Hi @nicola. It works. Very good solution!